# How to trigger an API every 3 seconds in the vue framework?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am a vue beginner and would like to ask a question!
My English is not good but I try to describe my problem completely, thank you.

Currently I use `vue` to learn how to access the API, but I hope to be able to automatically touch the API again every 3 seconds to update the screen, but I really don’t know how to achieve this?

Hope to get your help, thank you again for watching my question.

[My example](https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/poPqjVE)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `setInterval` in created hook that calls the method that loads the data :

```
Vue.createApp({
    data() {
    return {
      status: true,
      data: [],
      interval:null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    reNew() {
      axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5").then(
      (response) =>
          // console.log(response)
          (this.data = response.data.results)
      )
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.reNew()
  },
  created(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() =>{
      this.reNew()},3000)
  },
  destroyed(){
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your offer! Such useful help, thank you again for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setInterval` method.

This would execute the function every 3 seconds.

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
// fetch data...
}, 3000);
```